# How do I get the years in between 2 dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my table, I have a 'start_date' and 'end_date' column,

eg:

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2000/12/12 | 2010/10/12 |
| 1988/12/12 | 2003/04/03 |
| 1994/12/12 | 2008/09/21 |

What is the statement that I need to use to extract the years between the start & end date?
I want to create & view another column called ***AS 'num_years_worked'*** but I'm not sure what to input at the front.

Tried a few variations from Google but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, try editing this question so we can actually help you. Do take care to include [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just select the `YEAR` of both dates and build the difference of them:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date,
YEAR(end_date) - YEAR(start_date) AS difference
FROM yourtable;
```

You can also use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` for that:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,start_date,end_date) AS difference
FROM yourtable;
```

The difference is that this only "counts" entire years, so you might get different results compared to the first option.

Try out which better meets your requirements.

See here a working example according to your sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u02uDx8V)

Comment: The correctness depends on the OP task... the result does not equal to the **complete** years amount between specified dates. For example, it will give 1 year difference between 2021-12-31 and 2022-01-01 whereas the difference is 1 day only.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it out using this query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR , start_date ,    end_date) from table
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax, this does not work in sql server.